# Reduce queries to the same Django model when using Model.objects.all()

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need to perform aggregate sum on multiple columns from the same model and currently there are 7 queries base on my current setup below

```
def traffic_list(request, template_name='traffic_list.html'):
    traffic = Traffic.objects.all()
    total_sessions = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('sessions')).get('sessions__sum')
    total_new_users = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('new_users')).get('new_users__sum')
    total_reminder = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('reminder')).get('reminder__sum')
    total_campaigns = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('campaigns')).get('campaigns__sum')
    total_new_sales = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('new_sales')).get('new_sales__sum')
    total_sales_renewals = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('sales_renewals')).get('sales_renewals__sum')
```

I know there has to be a DRY way of doing this.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in one query:

```
traffic = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('sessions'),
                                          Sum('new_users'),
                                          ...)
traffic_sessions = traffic.get('sessions_sum')
...
```

Comment: Great!  I am down to 2 queries.  Thank you.